# Can't hide/change battery icon on Doogee S60

Tags: battery, 7.0-nougat, notification-bar, notification-icons, doogee

I'm using a Doogee S60, on Android 7.0 Nougat, rooted, with Xposed and GravityBox installed. I'm seeing this weird issue where my status bar has a non-standard battery icon, and I can't seem to either hide it or find out where it's coming from.

[image]

Turning off the battery icon in the GravityBox tweaks just moves the signal icon closer to the point where it starts to overlap with the battery icon. If I select a different battery icon, it just adds it overlapping.

[image]

[image]

In addition, if I open an app that makes the status bar background white, the battery icon colour doesn't change with the rest, making it mostly invisible.

[image]

I've looked in all the settings I can think of/find (including System Settings, System UI Tuner, GravityBox, and my launcher settings), and have no idea how to get rid of this. I just want the stock battery icon, or failing that, add a custom one. Either way, I want this battery icon gone.

Does anybody have any ideas about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The answer lies in build.prop!

All credit for this goes to [Nephiel](https://forum.xda-developers.com/member.php?u=6220053) on XDA-Developers ([this post](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=76996973&postcount=351), specifically).

The Doogee S60 has the setting `battery_view_land_show`, which is defaulted to `yes`.
On a rooted phone, this setting can be changed easily using BuildProp Editor.
Set the value to `no`, reboot the phone, et voila! Back to the standard battery icon, and all expected behavior from GravityBox and such!